# Angular 6 unit testing with ngx-translate dependency

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-test

I have an `angular 6` application with `ngx-translate/core@10.0.2`. Trying to use a `CustomLoader` with hard-coded values. But something is not quite right.

**Test**

```
class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
   return of({
      'DETAILS': {
        'PIN_ENTRY': {              
          'INPUT': {
            'ERRORS': {
              'INVALID': 'Blah',
              'INELIGIBLE': 'Blah Blah'
            }
          }
        }
      }
  });
 }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  imports: [
    ... // Elided for brevity
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: CustomLoader}
    })
  ],      
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.translateService.getTranslation('DETAILS.PIN_ENTRY.INPUT').pipe(first()).subscribe(translations => {      
    this.errorTranslations = translations['ERRORS'];
  });
}
```

The issue is, `translate` inside the `subscribe` is always 'DETAILS.PIN_ENTRY.INPUT'. I also added a logging statement in `CustomLoader#getTranslation`, to see if it was loaded, but couldn't see the output.

What is wrong with my set up?

Comment: First of all, `DETAILS.PIN_ENTRY.INPUT` is an object, not a string. Then, you haven't showed the way you're testing the component so hard to help. But as there's an observable you should use fakeAsync.

Comment: @maxime1992, that was it, missing fakeAsync. If you reword your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing a component that has values inside an observable you should use either `async` or `fakeAsync` within your test.

I think that `fakeAsync` might be your best option:

```
describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    // create your component

    // move forward in time
    tick();

    expect(component.errorTranslations).toEqual(yourError);
  })
})
```